# Error while exiting a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm creating a program in which the user enters a list of names and the computer then prints it out any names which have been duplicated. The code I have so far is:

```
names = []
final = []

enter = raw_input('Enter the name')
while enter != 'exit':
    names.append(enter)
    enter = raw_input('Enter the name')

for i in names:
    for a in (names):
        a = i + 1
        if a == i:
            final.append(i)

print final
```

I get an error when it reaches

```
a = i + 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you expect that for loop to do?

Comment: if you're assigning `a = i + 1` the following `if` condition, `if a == i:`,  will never be true...

Comment: `i` is a character string, you can't add `1` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find duplicates by doing this (in place of your `for` loops)

```
print set(x for x in names if names.count(x) > 1)
```

This is going to return a `set` of values that appears in the `names` variable more than one time.

---

```
names = []
final = []

enter = raw_input('Enter the name')
while enter != 'exit':
    names.append(enter)
    enter = raw_input('Enter the name')

print(set(x for x in names if names.count(x) > 1))
```

Output:

```
Enter the nameAndy
Enter the nameAndy
Enter the nameAndy
Enter the nameBob
Enter the nameGeorge
Enter the nameAndy
Enter the nameBob
Enter the nameexit
set(['Bob', 'Andy'])
```

---

`Bob` and `Andy` were entered more than once. George was not, thus doesn't appear in the set.

Comment: BTW: The list comprehension is unnecessary overhead in the `set()` construction, the generator is sufficient: `set(x for x in names if names.count(x) > 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign to a string object, if you want to get the strings that have duplicates in your list you better to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which returns a Counter object, then you can extract the names that those count is more than one.

```
from collections import Counter

for name,cnt in Counter(names):
    if cnt>1:
       print name
```